# EF Code First Fluent API - Cascade Delete

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-relationship, asp.net-identity-2

I have two models:

```
public class User
{
   .....
   public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set;}
}


public class UserProfile
{
   .....
   public virtual User User { get; set;}
}
```

The `User` is the master table and the relation is one to one. One user has only one UserProfile.

How can I define the relationship between User and UserProfile using EF CodeFirst Fluent API in such a way that when I delete one user from User table the user profile from Userprofile is also deleted?

Comment: make relationships...

Comment: I kinda know that but how can I do it in EF code first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346870/entity-framework-code-first-how-can-i-create-a-one-to-many-and-a-one-to-one-rel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`WillCascadeOnDelete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696319%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
    .HasKey(c => c.Id)
    .HasRequired(c => c.User)
    .WithRequiredDependent(c => c.UserProfile)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```