# Entity Framework one-to-many and many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

im currently learning the entity framework and been miserably failing with this task for a couple of days... I would like to achieve the following Database Scheme:

```
TableA:
ClassA_ID
ClassB_ID(foreign key - one to one)

TableATableB:(one-to-many relationship)
ClassA_ID
ClassB_ID

TableB:
ClassA_ID(foreign key - one to one)
ClassB_ID
```

So I Actually want a specific one to one relationship from Class A to Class B and a one to many Relationship from ClassA to ClassB.

My C# Code Looks like this:

Class A:

```
public static int idcounter;
[Key]
public int id { get; set; }
public virtual List<ClassB> allClassB { get; set; }
public virtual ClassB currentClassB { get; set; }
public int? currentClassBID { get; set; }

public ClassA(){
    idcounter++;
    id = idcounter;
    allClassB = new List<ClassB>();
    currentClassB = new ClassB();
    currentClassBID = currentClassB.id;
    MyContext.add(this);
}
```

Class B:

```
public static int idcounter;
[Key]
public int id { get; set; }
public virtual ClassA owner { get; set; }
public int? ownerID { get; set; }

public ClassB(ClassA a){
    idcounter++;
    id = idcounter;
    owner = a;
    ownerID =  a.id;
}
```

MyContext:

```
public static void add(ClassA a)
    {
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext ())
        {
            context.setB.Add(a.currentClassB);
            context.setA.Add(a);
            context.SaveChanges();           
        }
    }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>().HasOptional(x => x.currentClassB ).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.currentClassBID ).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().HasOptional(x => x.ClassA).WithMany(x => x.allClassB).HasForeignKey(x => x.ownerID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false) ;
    }
```

Its pretty similar to this question 
[Entity Framework Code First: How can I create a One-to-Many AND a One-to-One relationship between two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346870/entity-framework-code-first-how-can-i-create-a-one-to-many-and-a-one-to-one-rel) 
but I just get a Circular Exception when saving.

```
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may 
exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated 
values.
```

Its pretty weird that after

```
context.setA.Add(a);
```

it adds currentClassB into allClassB without me ever mention that... it Even suddenly does that when i dont

```
allClassB = new List<ClassB>();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Who needs coding conventions, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `InverseProperty` as shown below.

```
[InverseProperty("allClassB")]
public virtual ClassB currentClassB { get; set; }
public int? currentClassBID { get; set; }
```

[**DataAnnotations - InverseProperty Attribute:**](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: thank you very much! Thats the missing puzzle piece :)